# findViewById with reverse search does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm confused right now. I expect, that something, which works one way, also works reversed as well. But apparently not... I'm creating a view programmatically in my the class `PlayerView`. In the method `player_table` I'm assigning an onclick listener. And that works perfectly fine. However in the class `PlayerLifePoints_Functions` I have created the onclick method. The method itself works fine. The problem is the following: I'm assigning id's manually (to make my work in future process steps easier). Now I can read the id from an element, which was clicked. However if I want to find exactly this element by the ID (e.g. 400) it does return an error:

> Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference at ...PlayerLifePoints_Functions.onClick(PlayerLifePoints_Functions.java:21) -> The line with the log command

I have no idea why. I have also tried using getParent(), but that does not work either. Any ideas, where the problem could be?

> Class PlayerView

```
public class PlayerView extends View {

    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    private int player_loop;
    private int player_count;

    public PlayerView(Context context, int player_count){
        super(context);
        setPlayer_count(player_count);
    }

    public ScrollView create_scrollView(){

        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(getContext());
        ScrollView.LayoutParams scroll_params = new ScrollView.LayoutParams(
                ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        scrollView.setLayoutParams(scroll_params);
        scrollView.addView(create_relativeLayout());

        return scrollView;
    }

    public HorizontalScrollView create_relativeLayout(){

        HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(getContext());

        relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
        create_Player_Table_Layout();

        horizontalScrollView.addView(relativeLayout);
        return horizontalScrollView;

    }

    public void create_Player_Table_Layout(){

        for(player_loop = 1; player_loop <= player_count; player_loop++){

            relativeLayout.addView(player_table(getResources().getString(R.string.dummy_player_name) + player_loop, player_loop));

        }
    }

    public TableLayout player_table(String playername, int playernumber){

        tableLayout = new TableLayout(getContext());
        tableLayout.setId(playernumber * 1000);

        if (playernumber > 1) {

            //TABLE PLACEMENT
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tbl_params_New = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tbl_params_New.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, (playernumber - 1) * 1000);
            tableLayout.setLayoutParams(tbl_params_New);
        }

        //Add Playername
        TableRow row_playername = new TableRow(getContext());
        TextView view_name = new TextView(getContext());

        TableRow.LayoutParams view_name_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        view_name_params.setMargins(20,20,20,20);

        view_name.setLayoutParams(view_name_params);
        view_name.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view_name.setText(playername);
        view_name.setTextSize(20);
        view_name.setId(playernumber * 100);

        //OnClickListener
        PlayerName_Functions listener_name = new PlayerName_Functions();
        view_name.setOnClickListener(listener_name);

        row_playername.addView(view_name);
        tableLayout.addView(row_playername);

        //Add Lifepoints
        TableRow row_lifepoints = new TableRow(getContext());
        TextView view_lifepoints = new TextView(getContext());

        TableRow.LayoutParams view_lifepoints_params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        view_lifepoints_params.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 20);

        view_lifepoints.setText("40");
        view_lifepoints.setTextSize(40);
        view_lifepoints.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view_lifepoints.setId(playernumber * 100 + 10);
        view_lifepoints.setLayoutParams(view_lifepoints_params);

        //OnClickListener
        PlayerLifePoints_Functions listener_lifepoints = new PlayerLifePoints_Functions();
        view_lifepoints.setOnClickListener(listener_lifepoints);

        row_lifepoints.addView(view_lifepoints);
        tableLayout.addView(row_lifepoints);

        for(int opponent_loop = 1; opponent_loop <= player_count; opponent_loop++){
            tableLayout.addView(commander_damage_from_player(player_loop, opponent_loop));
        }

        return tableLayout;
    }
```

> Class PlayerLifePoints (Containing the OnClick Function implemented in the class above)

```
public class PlayerLifePoints_Functions extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        TextView textView = (TextView) v;

        String lp = textView.getText().toString();
        int id = textView.getId();
        int playernumber =  Character.getNumericValue(String.valueOf(id).charAt(0));

        Log.d("Test", "ID: " + findViewById(v.getId()).getId());

//        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Update_LifePoints.class);
//        intent.putExtra( "Update Reason", "Test");
////        intent.putExtra("Player Name", playername);
//        intent.putExtra("Lifepoints", lp);
//
//        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Comment: `PlayerLifePoints_Functions` should not extend any `Activity` class or subclass. You cannot instantiate Activities yourself. They must be instantiated and setup by the system. If you really want a separate class for your `OnClickListener`, then you'll have to pass it either the `Activity` to call `findViewById()` on, or whatever `View`s it needs. I really wouldn't recommend either. Why can't you just use an inner class for your `OnClickListener`?

Comment: That makes sense. I've put it now into an inner class, yet it does not produce the expected result. What confuses me: `findViewbyID` does not work, if I manually pass an ID (e.g. 400), because of the required int structure (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387193/passing-variable-into-findviewbyid). But how do I use my IDs now?

Comment: You're passing 400? `tableLayout.setId(playernumber * 1000)` – Looks like it's going to start at at least 1000. Also, this doesn't really make sense – `findViewById(v.getId()).getId()`. That's getting the clicked `View`'s ID to find itself by its own ID, just to get its lD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `PlayerLifePoints_Functions` cannot use `findViewById` because it does not have content. Usually activities are started with [Intents](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) and they inflate a layout by overriding the [onCreate](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities#oncreate) method.

## If you just want to make it work, you can use:

```
v.getRootView().findViewById(v.getId()).getId());
```

In that case you do not need to extend from `AppCompatActivity`

### Or better just get rid of the class:

```
view_lifepoints.setOnClickListener( View.OnClickListener {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

      TextView textView = (TextView) v;

      String lp = textView.getText().toString();
      int id = textView.getId();
      int playernumber =  Character.getNumericValue(String.valueOf(id).charAt(0));

      Log.d("Test", "ID: " + findViewById(v.getId()).getId());
  }

);
```

---

In general:
I would recommend not putting your whole logic into a view, but more down into a lower layer. Having it in the activity would already be an improvement for prototyping. If your code grows, it may make sense to switch to [MVP](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/) or [MVVM](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-live).

Google has some great resources to get you started:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/